# Extending a struct with generic array type specification

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible to do something like this at all in swift 4?

```
extension MyStruct where T: [Object] { }
```

I thought there has to be a way as this compiles:

```
let property = MyStruct<[Object]>()
```

My struct would than look like this:

```
struct MyStruct<T> { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to restrict `T` to be *equal* to some type:

```
extension MyStruct where T == [Object] {

}
```

A constraint `T: P` would be used to restrict `T` to *conform* to (or *inherit* from) `P`.

Comment: I am an idiot! yes :) ... forgot about the == :))) thanks a lot!